# Sum of x highest per row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table with the columns `(userid, score)`. I want to group the `userid`'s and get a column with the sum of the X highest scores for each `userid`.

E.g. For the sum of the two highest scores:

```
userid | score
-------+-------
01     | 1
01     | 1
01     | 2
02     | 1
02     | 2
02     | 3
```

to:

```
userid | scoresum
-------+----------
01     | 3
02     | 5
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this in MYSQL.

Comment: do u want last two highest number sum is ur output????

Comment: @K6t yeah, in the example I assume the sum of the two highest scores. Edited the Q make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  userid,
(
select sum(highestscores)
from (
  select * 
  from userscore us2 
  where us2.userid = us1.userid 
  order by score desc limit 5
)
) as scoresum
from ( select distinct userid from userscore ) us1
```

so basically you need a sub query to get the 5 highest scores. you then sum those with another sub query. and you run that whole business for each unique user_id from your one and only table, userscore.

Comment: I can't seem to get this query to work. MySQL complains about `Unknown column 'us1.userid' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: seems like variable scope doesn't go nested into there. sorry. i'll provide another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(MAX(col.name)) From table name Group by usedid
```

Comment: I don't think thats what he wanted. **with the sum of the X highest scores**

Comment: I don't think he ment that because if you look at the desired output and compare that with the above output it's not just a sum of all scores

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple query that gives you all the data. now you just have to split the top_scores by /,/ and then add them up in your code. an alternative is a stored procedure but i think this is simpler. good luck.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) top_scores
from userscore
group by userid
```